# Creating a responsive website, showing as mobile design in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design

I am creating a website using a responsive template and cannot get it to look correct in IE8. At the moment it is displaying the mobile version of the site and I don't know why.

I would like the design to be fixed width in IE8 (and lower) and continue to be responsive in all other browsers. How best could I do this?

The template is www.prowebdesign.ro/simple-responsive-template-free/

Answer (score 2):

Media Queries are not supported in IE8 and lower. If you are building mobile first then this quite possibly will make IE8 display the mobile version

You would need to use a [polyfill like respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to add the media query functionality to lower versions of ie.

You also have conditional classes set in your document based on the version of ie. You can use these to override the container width and set a fixed width.

```
.lt-ie9 #container {
    width:1024px;
}
```